# Tomcat not recognizing new jar

Tags: tomcat, jar, tomcat7

I've got a web app using Tomcat 7.0. I have a jar that the web app uses to perform some tasks, the jar sits in the lib folder. Normally when I change the code for that jar I replace the jar in lib with the new jar, restart Tomcat and the new jar is then used.

I have followed that same process again (delete old jar, add new jar, restart Tomcat) for the latest code change to the jar but now Tomcat doesn't seem to recognize the new jar, it seems as if it is still using the old jar even though it has been replaced by the new jar (new functionality that was added in the code is not happening but functionality that was removed is still happening).

Any ideas on what is going on here?

Comment: maybe another version of the jar in another location. What do you mean by `lib`? `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: I don't think there is another version somewhere else as I'm deleting the old version not moving it somewhere else.

Comment: check if your old jar is not in referenced libraries. And if it is just do Right click + remove from build path. 
If you haven't added it in classpath then just delete old jar, add new jar  clean project and delete server the instance. Worst case - do the above stuff  and do this.... stop eclipse, go to workspace delete meta data folder , opene eclipse and import your project into workspace again. This should work if everythign that you have done is right.(Eclipse behaves weird sometimes)

Comment: The jar is a stand-alone project that I can do a clean and build on so that's fine but but the web app is running on a different server and is out of my control really, all I do is replace the jar that that web app uses and then restart the server.